# Orbit-induced attitude errors

Tags: orbit, attitude

I have been trying to obtain the pitch-yaw-roll errors induced by known errors in the in-track, cross-track and radial coordinates or LVLH errors.

How is the relation of these error sets derived?

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem statement?

Comment: If, say you are given that the in-track error is 10 Km, cross-track 2Km, radial 1km, how do these errors in these coordinates, which is a spacecraft  body system, translate to pitch, roll, and yaw errors. It is easy to see how, for example, an error in the in-track position would affect pitch, but what I'm trying to derive is a formal relational expression among these errors.

Comment: The problem is underspecified. What control law governs the sat? Is it nadir-looking? What ref frame are you using?

Comment: Reference frame is LVLH. nadir pointing. three axis stabilization.

Comment: As for control, it s PID

Comment: Orbit attitude error coupling is treated extensively in [Markley & Crassidis' *Fundamentals of Spacecraft Attitude Determination and Control*](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4939-0802-8).